# list S3 files in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

I am new to Pyspark and trying to use spark.read method to read S3 files in dataframe. I was able to successfully read one file from S3. Now I need to iterate and read all the files in a bucket.

My question is how to iterate and get all the files one by one.

I used to do this in in Python using boto3, is there something similar in Pyspark.
s3_client.list_objects

Comment: Depending on permissions and where you are running pyspark, you can install `boto3`. Otherwise, you might want to look into wildcarding. Something like `spark.read.parquet('s3://my_bucket/*/*/*')`

Answer (score 4):

What if you use the `SparkSession` and `SparkContext` to read the files at once and then loop through thes s3 directory by using **[wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles.html)** method. You can utilize the `s3a` connector in the url which allows to read from s3 through Hadoop.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('S3Example').getOrCreate()

s3_bucket = 'your-bucket'
s3_path = f's3a://{s3_bucket}/my-directory/'

# List files S3
file_list = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(s3_path).map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()

for file_path in file_list:
    print(file_path)
```

Please note, above I've only retrieved the file paths. If you want both, you can avoid only extracting the file path (x[0] in the lambda), and get both.

```
file_tuple = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(s3_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `s3fs` - `pip install s3fs`

And can try below code -

```
import s3fs

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
fs.ls('my-bucket')
```

Also see this [doc](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Another way is using `hadoopFile`:

```
SparkContext.hadoopFile("s3a://bucket_name/prefix)
```

refer to this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.hadoopFile.html).

Comment: I have already authenticated S3 connection in my spark session. If I use s3fs method, I will need one more connection to S3 just to list files and then spark session to read files. This is why I am trying to figure out if there is a way to list files using same spark session.

Comment: In that case you can use `SparkContext.hadoopFile("s3a://bucket_name/prefix)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other answers;

You can still use boto3 lib to get the list of objects with full path like below:

```py
response = boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
full_paths_list = list()
for obj in response["Contents"]:
    full_path = f's3://full_paths_list bucket}/{obj["Key"]}'
    full_paths_list.append(full_path)
```

Now, you have files list so you can read them with pyspark like below:

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(*full_paths_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `boto3` with pyspark. List objects in an S3 bucket and read them into a PySpark DataFrame.

1. Iterate over the list of objects and read each file into a PySpark DataFrame using the spark.read method.
2. Append each DataFrame to a list and then union all dataframes into one using the reduce function.

> ```
> import boto3
> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>
> # Create a SparkSession
> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Read from S3").getOrCreate()
>
> # Set up a boto3 client
> s3 = boto3.client('s3')
>
> # List all objects in the S3 bucket
> bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
> prefix = "path-to-folder-within-bucket/"  # optional: if you want to read only files in a particular folder
> objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
>
> # Read each file into a PySpark DataFrame
> dataframes = []
> for obj in objects['Contents']:
>     file_name = obj['Key']
>     s3_path = f's3://{bucket_name}/{file_name}'
>     df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(s3_path)
>     dataframes.append(df)
>
> # Union all dataframes into one
> final_df = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), dataframes)
>
> # Show the final dataframe
> final_df.show()
> ```

Comment: Thanks Nipun. One basic question since I am just starting, I see that in boto 3 client initiation you are not using AWS Secret etc. Does this mean you are suggesting store them in a common config file and it will be automatically used from that config in both boto3 and Spark session ?

Comment: never use inferSchema reading CSV files off an object store unless you want to force spark to read every file during query planning.

Comment: @PythonDeveloper you can add it to common config file but then you need to add s3 secret in the boto3.client and reference the secret from environment file.

Comment: @stevel Yes you are correct. I've updated my answer based on your input.